# Dual job within German university with 25% contract

Tags: university, germany

If someone currently working 100% with employer 1 in a public job. Is it possible to get employed by a university or public organisation (employer 2) with 25% or 35% contract after having a Master's or Doctorate degree?

The dual job includes engagement in some activity within the group.

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you mean by "dual job". Do you want to be employed by two different employers, working 25 % or 35 % for each? Generally, all kinds of part time contracts are allowed.

Comment: I have edited the text, please relook it.

Comment: What does the sentence "The dual job includes engagement in some activity within the group" mean?

Comment: Look into regulations for "Nebentätigkeit" applying to both employer 1 and 2. It's generally not uncommon but you have to follow the rules regarding time extent, approval, etc.

Comment: @silvado thanks for your answer, in practice, have you seen it? I couldn't explore it much.

Answer (score 5):

No, this is not legally possible in Germany.

By law (see [*Arbeitszeitgesetz*](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/arbzg/BJNR117100994.html)) you are only allowed to work 8 hours per day on average (exceptions exist but are unlikely to be applicable in the case as described). A workweek can include Saturday, i.e., be six days. Your maximum legal hours per week are thus 6 * 8 = 48 hours.

Assuming your 100 % job is 39 hours per week, that leaves 9 hours if you are working saturdays. 25 % of 39 hours is 9.75 hours. Your total would therefore be 48.75 hours per week, which is just slightly above the legal maximum for a six-day workweek.

Comment: Furthermore, Employer 1 has to be notified and has to declare that they are fine with your second job.

Comment: Depends on what is the "public job" with employer 1. Arbeitszeitgesetz only applies to "Arbeiter und Angestellte", so for example not to "Beamte", moreover there are some exceptions.

Comment: @silvado OP mentions an employer. Beamte are not employees and don't have an employer.

Comment: Sure, but I wouldn't trust the English terms to always capture these nuances correctly.

Comment: @silvado And I would be extremely surprised if OP was asking about the rules for a Beamter. I mention exceptions in my answer.

Comment: Well the OP has another question about a dual job for a professor in Europe so it's a possibility that this is about rules for Beamte.

Comment: If OP is asking about edge cases it's their job to make that obvious in the question.

Comment: Thanks for providing all the comments, if it is that is an issue, how do other people do the side jobs like working in a company and engaging with a chair in university. Many of my colleagues don't want to work extra as volunteers.  My concern is not in terms to earn money but how others are doing it?

Comment: @GautamShahi If you're just looking at a cooperation with another research group most would do that without direct remuneration from the cooperation partner; instead we get joint publications and possibly research funding in joint projects. Cooperation with industry can also be done by consulting.

Comment: @GautamShahi One obvious way of having two jobs is if the first one is actually not a full time job, but rather a 50% or 75% position. This is actually quite common, especially when one of the positions is a "scientific employee" position, for which in many fields of research, having a full time position is an exception rather than the norm.

Comment: @GautamShahi It's unclear what exactly "others are doing". What are you actually trying to ask?

Comment: One more point: self-employed (science is by definition a freelancer profession in Germany) are not subject to the Arbeitszeitgesetz. However, when I was asking my research institute employer about running a freelance side-business, their acceptance letter told me that I still need to make sure the Arbeitszeitgesetz is not violated.

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX "science is by definition a freelancer profession in Germany" I don't think that's correct. Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: @Roland: sure, §18 EStG "Zu der freiberuflichen Tätigkeit gehören die selbständig ausgeübte wissenschaftliche [...] Tätigkeit"

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX You are misinterpreting that. Most researchers in Germany are not "selbständig". We get a wage and pay wage tax as any other employees. I know (of) a few researchers who are actual freelancers (and those are addressed by the cited definition), but that is the exception not the norm. I don't know the rules for people with a stipend. Maybe those are freelancers from a legal perspective.

Comment: @Roland: well, I know all three of them :-) and a scholarship is legally very different from both freelancing and employment. I should have been more clear, my point about the Arbeitszeitgesetz "sneaking in" to the realm of having a side business is true whether you do that as Freiberufler or gewerblich. Where the Freiberuf/freelancing comes into play is that setting up your business as Freiberufler is easier (burocratically). I'd therefore expect that among those who run a side business as scientists, most will choose Freiberuf for the setup. But yes, we are rare :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the specific constellation that you are interested in, but the first point to go to would be the personnel department at employer 1. If this is a public institution (university, research institute, or the like) they should have some guidelines about side jobs (Nebentätigkeit) that you need to follow. The specific regulations may depend on the type of your appointment (TVÖD, Beamter, ...). If this is a larger institution you can probably find the applicable guidelines on their intranet (possibly in German only).

If everything works out with employer 1, you also need to check with employer 2 which regulations apply.

For professors at German universities, side jobs are generally possible (subject to specific rules) and are being used. I know cases where the side job was in industry or other universities abroad. I don't personally know of a case where the second employer was another German public institution, but I think it should also be possible.

Comment: @silvaod, thanks for the detailed description; I agree with you on the overall description.  Only the last paragraph raises the question of whether a professor is doing a side job in a private company or running their own company. The number of hours is more than 9-10 hours, and even it's unofficially. This is my exact question.

Comment: @GautamShahi The professor will have to ask for permission before starting the side activity, and normally if it's beyond a certain time limit (probably 20% of the regular working time) it would not be allowed. I think this will also apply to running an own company, but you'll have to check the regulations that are relevant for you, and, if in doubt, ask you administration.

Comment: @silvado: the university (or the Land) may decide that the 2nd position is in their interest and free their employee/Beamer for x h/wk. While I don't know for sure, I think this is how people who are professor or teach at a university plus have a position at a non-university research institute do it (I know several such people). (Works also on lower level: when I was employee of the university during my PhD and got a scholarship, the university decided that it was in their interest to allow me to have the scholarship, and we agreed to have the employment contract "hibernate" for that time)